# Inequality comparison

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Suppose we are given:

$$
p_1>p_2 \\
a>b \\
c<d
$$

Where $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers and $p_{1},p_{2}$ are positive natural numbers.

What can we infer about the following inequality:

$$
\left[ \left( \dfrac{a}{a+b} \right)^{p_1} \times 
\left( \dfrac{b}{a+b} \right)^{p_2} \right] \;\;?\;\;
\left[ \left(\dfrac{c}{c+d} \right)^{p_1} \times 
\left( \dfrac{d}{c+d} \right)^{p_2} \right]
$$

Actually I want to know `?` should be `<` or `>`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot infer anything. On one hand, if you take $b = \varepsilon \approx 0$  and $c >> \varepsilon$, then LHS < RHS. On the other hand, if $c = \varepsilon \approx 0$ and $b >>  \varepsilon$, then LHS > RHS.

**EDIT**: Example:

Case (1): $a = d = 2, c = 1, b = 0.01, p_1 = 2$ and $p_2 = 1$:

$$LHS \approx 0.049257 < RHS \approx 0.07407$$

Case (2): $a = d = 2, c = 0.01, b = 1, p_1 = 2$ and $p_2 = 1$:

$$LHS \approx 0.148148 > RHS \approx 0.0000246$$.